# bash: In: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

This is the code I am using:

```
cd /home
if [ -d ${homedir} ]
   then ln -s /etc/cpbackup-exclude.conf ${homedir}/cpbackup-exclude.conf
fi
done
```

And now I am getting this error:

```
bash: In: command not found
```

I am trying to create a symlink to `cpbackup-exclude` for all accounts.

Comment: can you use the command from a shell outside a script?  what does `which ln` output?

Answer (score 9):

You have mistyped `ln (LN)` as `In (IN)` or something similar.  The correct command is `ln`, as in "Lima November".  The command `ln` abbreviates from the word "link", which is the primary function of the command.

Comment: +1 His original code (assuming it was pasted) has `ln`, but his reported error messages have `In`. Suggests that the path problem is still likely.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the $PATH variable is not set correctly during the execution of your script. Try using an absolute path to the ln command. Typically this would be `/bin/ln`.

Comment: If I try that I get this error 
bash: /bin/In: No such file or directory

Comment: What path does `which ln` output for you?

Comment: If there is neither `/usr/bin/ln` nor `/bin/ln`, then your system has been damaged and you need to reinstall parts of it.

Comment: @TJSingleton if `ln` yields `bash: ln: command not found` then `which ln` will yield nothing, or `bash: which: command not found`.

Comment: @TJSingleton `type -P` is a POSIX-compliant alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Use the absolute path:

```
/usr/bin/ln
```

Your ln utility may be here instead.

Comment: If I try that I get this error 
bash: /bin/In: No such file or directory